# Showing anamorphic mp4 video with video.js?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to create a video clip from a DVD and play it with video.js on a web page.

The source material on the DVD is in anamorphic format, i.e. it is stored with 720 x 576 pixels, but is meant to be displayed at 1024 x 576.

I've created a mp4 file using Handbrake with its 'strict' anamorphic setting.

VLC displays the resulting file correctly, i.e. the width is stretched to 16:9 eventhough VLC media information correctly reports 720 x 576 pixels.

When I try to view it with video.js using the html code below, the video is not stretched - but square pixels are assumed.

A Google search didn't reveal much, at least not in the context of anamorphic material.
Some postings suggest to change the width to "100%" or "auto", or put the video tag  into a DIV with definied dimensions.

However, the result is always the same. The dimensions of the player itself change but the displayed video remains "squished" with black bars at either side.

Is there an option I have not found, an encoding setting that I have overlooked, or a CSS trick that can strech the **video**'s width within the player? Or is it simply not possible?

Yes, I could scale the video to square pixels during encoding, but this seems to be a waste of space.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                document.createElement('video');document.createElement('audio');document.createElement('track');
        </script>
        <link href="file:///home/mike/videojs-demo/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="file:///home/mike/videojs-demo/video.js"></script>
        <title>video.js test</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <video id="example_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
        controls 
        preload="auto"
        width="1024"
        height="576"
        data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="file:///home/mike/videojs-demo/test2.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width and height attributes on a video element should solve your problem. But I see that you are using video.js and only an mp4 file. If, as I suspect, you're viewing the page in Firefox, which does not play mp4 in many cases, it is using the Flash fallback, which may not adjust the aspect ratio for you.

Try making a second `source` tag with a webm encoded version of the video. That will allow Firefox to play the video natively rather than with Flash, which should fix the problem and will get you better performance anyway.